# Python: search multiple values (list/array/series) contained in a dataframe (matrix), returning coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, xlwings

I have an excel file with about 1000 rows, 3 column of values and 1 column of "names" which can be used as index.

In Python, I would like to find all matching values from a list of numbers I enter (can be entered in another excel file or in code, not a problem), and I would like to have an output as a "list" of matched values, with row (index name) and column name.

As for now, I used Pandas to create a DataFrame with the 3 columns (A,B,C) of the excel file and all the rows, declaring column D as an index of the dataframe.

Using ".isin" I can obtain a matrix of BOOLs representing if any of the values in the target array is present in the whole dataframe. I then ask for the matchign "true" cases, and shows me the values.

WEAK PART OF MY CODE: I then reduce the DataFrame down to one column, to ignore NaN values, showing me matching values together with index (column D of my excel file).

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlwings as xw
...

target = np.array(anotherExcelsheet.Range((1,1),(100,1)).value)
outdf= valuesdf[valuesdf.isin(target_values)].dropna(how='all')
```

Now, my output is for example

```
123 AAA
333 BBB
444 GGG
```

while, I would like to have:

```
123 AAA , column 2
333 BBB , column 1
444 GGG , column 3
```

I don't care much of the aestetics of the output, or how to obtain it. 
Can be also something like:

```
AAA(2) : 123
BBB(1) : 333
GGG(3) : 444
```

The (n) tells the number of the column, as longs as it's understandable, it's fine.

Any help is heavily accepted, as then I will have a step-2 question after this.

Thank you!

Comment: Hello, you give output you like but no input exemple. It's hard to understand. Can you format your text for a better reading ?

Comment: Re-edited by moderator. Hope it looks better now...

as per inputs, I created a pd.DataFrame :

<code>
data = pd.DataFrame(ws.range((1,1), (1000,4)).value,
                          index=[ws.range((1,4),(1000,4)).value])
</code>

Comment: Hello, thanks but we still lack the original dataframe. How looks target_values ? valuesdf ? target ? I guess target_values is something like [123,333,444]

Comment: yes target is a list list of integers, converted into np.array